# Preg_replace cant replace what i need

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need some help with preg_replace. At my website I need to delete some things I don't need.
Here is an example:

```
[caption id="attachment_100951" align="alignleft" width="448" caption="THIS IS WHAT I NEED"] [/caption]
```

Ok, all I need from this string is: the text inside `caption="THIS TEXT"`,
every thing else I need to be deleted, I have used Google and tried some examples but nothing.
Maybe I need to use another function, but from what I have read on the internet this should replace .

Please help me, it's very important.
Thank you.

EDIT:

The code has some other things that i have forgot.

```
[caption id="attachment_100951" align="alignleft" width="448" caption="eaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]
<a href="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg">
<img class="size-full wp-image-100951" title="zjarr_banese1" src="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg" alt="eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" width="448" height="308" />
</a>
[/caption]
```

So i need to get the **CAPTION text** and delete every thing in 
[caption id="attachment_100951" align="alignleft" width="448" caption="eaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]

but not

```
<a href="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg">
<img class="size-full wp-image-100951" title="zjarr_banese1" src="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg" alt="eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" width="448" height="308" />
</a>
```

also want delete [/caption]

too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex :

```
$result = preg_replace('/\[caption\s+.*?caption\s*=(["\'])(.*?)\1.*?\[\/caption\]/', '$2', $subject);
```

will output :

```
THIS IS WHAT I NEED
```

when applied to :

```
[caption id="attachment_100951" align="alignleft" width="448" caption="THIS IS WHAT I NEED"] [/caption]
```

Updated answer based on your updated question :

```
$result = preg_replace('%\[caption\s+.*?caption\s*=(["\'])(.*?)\1\s*\](.*?)\[/caption\]%s', '$2\n$3', $subject);
```

The above regex applied to :

```
[caption id="attachment_100951" align="alignleft" width="448" caption="eaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]
<a href="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg">
<img class="size-full wp-image-100951" title="zjarr_banese1" src="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg" alt="eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" width="448" height="308" />
</a>
[/caption]
```

Will output :

```
    eaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

<a href="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg">
<img class="size-full wp-image-100951" title="zjarr_banese1" src="http://localhost/111baneease1.jpg" alt="eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" width="448" height="308" />
</a>
```

I am not sure if this is exactly what you wanted. Of course you can use the regex to match and do whatever you want with groups $2 and $3...

Comment: i would change the final `.*` to `.*?\[\/caption\]` so it can match multiple instances in a larger doc